# Kibana 6.3.0 Gauge - hide scrollbar in dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5, kibana-6

Any idea how to remove horizontal \ vertical scroll bar kibana dashboard[image]

Comment: Which browser do you have?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome..

Comment: @Val Any thought

Comment: Which version of Chrome? On PC or Mac?

Comment: Windows 10 laptop - chrome 67.0.3396.99